# Azure DevOps Pre and Post deployment scripts run randomly

Tags: azure-devops

I'm having an issue with my pre and post deployment scripts for my database project within my azure devops release.  These scripts do not run all the time and it seems to be random.  In my latest release, I added to the post deployment to removed some stored procedures that are no longer needed.  When I it was pushed out many different times to my acceptance environment, the pre and post deployment scripts didn't run every time.  Did anybody else have the same issue?

Thank you,

Shawn

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Are you use Classic Releases or Pipelines and what do your deployment steps look like?

Comment: Its a release under the pipelines section on the dashboard.  I have a SQL Deployment (Run on agent).  Then under that, I have 2 SQL Server database deploy using connection string.  Then for each deploy, I have pre and post deployment scripts. I can tell you that the DacPac is running fine for each database deploy.  The issue is just with the pre and post deployment scripts.